# Get value inbetween underscores at a certain occurance

Tags: regex, plsql

I'm trying to get the value in between 2 underscores at a certain occurrence.

Ex:

```
HOL_1026-03_OW_01.9000_01.3400_0.2800_CL_32, 0"_0, 0"_0, 0"_RR_NORM_CR-HSR_CR-SUP_ALLHOL-013_FCNO_NOFIN_VRA-010_HXHHH_.
```

I'm trying to extract the `"CR-HSR"` and `"CR-SUP"` from this. I originally came up with this

```
(?!(.*?_){8}).*(?=(.*?_){7}) and  (?!(.*?_){7}).*(?=(.*?_){6})
```

which works in regexr.com

I'm using this with PL/SQL and when I run the REGEXP_SUBSTR() method, It returns null.

Comment: Do you mean you need to exract two values from the string at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without lookarounds, you can repeat a group matching not an `_` followed by matching it.

```
^([^_]+_){12}([^_]+)
```

Then get the capture group 2 value.

```
SELECT regexp_substr('HOL_1026-03_OW_01.9000_01.3400_0.2800_CL_32, 0"_0, 0"_0, 0"_RR_NORM_CR-HSR_CR-SUP_ALLHOL-013_FCNO_NOFIN_VRA-010_HXHHH_.', '^([^_]+_){12}([^_]+)', 1,1,NULL,2) from dual;
```

Output

```
CR-HSR
```

To match `CR-SUP` you can change the quantifier from `{12}` to `{13}`

As an alternative, as shorter way might also be

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(c, '[^_]+', 1, 13)
```